# I'm getting an error trying to find the number of rows

Tags: pdf, salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I made a table using vf page, I want to count the rows of this table but I get the following error:
`Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number`
how can i fix this? thanks.

```
<apex:variable var="num" value="0" />
<apex:repeat value="{!list}" var="key">
     <apex:variable var="num" value="{!num + 1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by wrapping the 0 in curly braces like that {!0}